# Question regarding field extension and Galois Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Given fields: $A$ = $\Bbb{Q}$, $B = \Bbb{Q}(x)$, and $C = \Bbb{Q}(x,y)$, with $x$ = $(-1)^{2/3}$ and $y$ = $2^{1/3}$, what would be the field bases for $C:A$ and $B:A$ ? I got the basis for $B:A$ to be degree 2 as the minimal polynomial for $x$ is $x^{2}+x+1=0$, so the basis for would ${1,x}$. As for $C:A$, I decided that $C:B$ would be degree 3, since the minimal polynomial would be $x^{3}-2=0$, so by tower theorem $C:A$ degree would be 6, giving me a basis of $1,x,y,xy,y^{2}x,y^{2}$, with the hopes that these are all linearly independent in $\Bbb{Q}$. Is this reasoning/any of this correct?

Assuming this is correct, would the galois groups of $C:A$ and $B:A$ just be the permutations of (+/-) of the bases?

Comment: $x^3-1$ is not irreducible

Comment: Whoops ok. I guess that makes it $x^{2}+x+1$.

Comment: There appears to be some typo as $x = (-1)^{2/3} = 1$ so that $A = B$ and $[C:A] = 3$. Perhaps you wanted $x$ to be a non-real cube root of unity (and not of $-1$).

Comment: I actually meant $x$ $=$ $e^{2\pi i/3}$ but I decided to simplify so it was easier to type.

Comment: Yes the minimal polynomial of $e^{2i \pi / 3} = \zeta_3$ is $X^2+X+1$. Now let $ B = \mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi/3}), C = B(2^{1/3})$. Then $C$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and since $gcd(2,3)=1$ and $[B:\mathbb{Q}] = 2$, it stays irreducible over $B$, so yes what you wrote is correct. For the Galois group : note the automorphisms of $C/B$ send $2^{1/3}\to 2^{1/2} \zeta_3^k$, and those of $B/\mathbb{Q}$ send $\zeta_3 \to \zeta_3^m$